# How to stack layers in Keras without using Sequential()?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

If I have a keras layer L, and I want to stack N versions of this layer (with different weights) in a keras model, what's the best way to do that? Please note that here N is large and controlled by a hyper param. If N is small then this not a problem (we can just manually repeat a line N times). So let's assume N > 10 for example.

If the layer has only one input and one output, I can do something like:

```
m = Sequential()
for i in range(N):
    m.add(L)
```

But this is not working if my layer actually takes multiple inputs. For example, if my layer has the form z = L(x, y), and I would like my model to do:

```
x_1 = L(x_0, y)
x_2 = L(x_1, y)
...
x_N = L(x_N-1, y)
```

Then Sequential wouldn't do the job. I think I can subclass a keras model, but I don't know what's the cleanest way to put N layers into the class. I can use a list, for example:

```
class MyModel(Model):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyModel, self).__init__()
        self.layers = []
        for i in range(N):
            self.layers.append(L)
    def call(self, inputs):
        x = inputs[0]
        y = inputs[1]
        for i in range(N):
            x = self.layers[i](x, y)
        return x
```

But this is not ideal, as keras won't recognize these layers (it seems not thinking list of layers as "checkpointables"). For example, MyModel.variables would be empty, and MyModel.Save() won't save anything.

I also tried to define the model using the functional API, but it won't work in my case as well. In fact if we do

```
def MyModel():
    input = Input(shape=...)
    output = SomeLayer(input)
    return Model(inputs=input, outputs=output)
```

It won't run if SomeLayer itself is a custom model (it raises NotImplementedError).

Any suggestions?

Comment: Maybe you should have a look at the much more flexible [Functional API](https://keras.io/getting-started/functional-api-guide/) of Keras

Comment: @desertnaut : as I said in the question, the functional API won't work for customized layers. (It raises NotImplementedError.)

Comment: Yes, in an edit *after* my comment... :(

Comment: @desertnaut Sorry! I didn't see your comment when I did the editing....

Comment: I think you should expand on why you think you can't use the Functional API, and what code you are using in this case and what exact errors/stacktraces you get.

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro I rewrote the last paragraph to explain the issue with functional API.

Comment: Sorry but you haven't added any new information. Just to clarify, your model class is using the functional API to call your layers, so its perfectly possible to use it.

Comment: By model I mean the MyModel class.

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro In the MyModel class approach (the subclass approach), the call() method of the class itself works, but keras cannot recognize those weights in util method. For example, MyModel.variables would be empty, and MyModel.Save() won't save anything. This is because Keras is not smart enough to understand that self.layers is actually containing trainable layers - it only recognizes direct layer member, not list of layers as a member when extracting variables.

Comment: No, it doesn't work because you are not doing it right, and you are not explaining what is the problem with the Functional API. Without that there is no real way for us to help you.

Answer (score 4):

Not sure if I've got your question right, but I guess that you could use the functional API and `concatenate` or `add` layers as it is shown in Keras applications, like, [ResNet50](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/keras-2/keras/applications/resnet50.py#L74) or [InceptionV3](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/keras-2/keras/applications/inception_v3.py#L188) to build "non-sequential" networks.

**UPDATE**

In one of my projects, I was using something like this. I had a custom layer (it was not implemented in my version of Keras, so I've just manually "backported" the code into my notebook).

```
class LeakyReLU(Layer):
    """Leaky version of a Rectified Linear Unit backported from newer Keras 
    version."""

    def __init__(self, alpha=0.3, **kwargs):
        super(LeakyReLU, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.supports_masking = True
        self.alpha = K.cast_to_floatx(alpha)

    def call(self, inputs):
        return tf.maximum(self.alpha * inputs, inputs)

    def get_config(self):
        config = {'alpha': float(self.alpha)}
        base_config = super(LeakyReLU, self).get_config()
        return dict(list(base_config.items()) + list(config.items()))

    def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape):
        return input_shape
```

Then, the model:

```
def create_model(input_shape, output_size, alpha=0.05, reg=0.001):
    inputs = Input(shape=input_shape)

    x = Conv2D(16, (3, 3), padding='valid', strides=(1, 1), 
               kernel_regularizer=l2(reg), kernel_constraint=maxnorm(3),
               activation=None)(inputs)
    x = BatchNormalization()(x)
    x = LeakyReLU(alpha=alpha)(x)
    x = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(x)

    x = Conv2D(32, (3, 3), padding='valid', strides=(1, 1),
               kernel_regularizer=l2(reg), kernel_constraint=maxnorm(3),
               activation=None)(x)
    x = BatchNormalization()(x)
    x = LeakyReLU(alpha=alpha)(x)
    x = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(x)

    x = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), padding='valid', strides=(1, 1),
               kernel_regularizer=l2(reg), kernel_constraint=maxnorm(3),
               activation=None)(x)
    x = BatchNormalization()(x)
    x = LeakyReLU(alpha=alpha)(x)
    x = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(x)

    x = Conv2D(128, (3, 3), padding='valid', strides=(1, 1),
               kernel_regularizer=l2(reg), kernel_constraint=maxnorm(3),
               activation=None)(x)
    x = BatchNormalization()(x)
    x = LeakyReLU(alpha=alpha)(x)
    x = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(x)

    x = Conv2D(256, (3, 3), padding='valid', strides=(1, 1),
               kernel_regularizer=l2(reg), kernel_constraint=maxnorm(3),
               activation=None)(x)
    x = BatchNormalization()(x)
    x = LeakyReLU(alpha=alpha)(x)
    x = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(x)

    x = Flatten()(x)
    x = Dense(500, activation='relu', kernel_regularizer=l2(reg))(x)
    x = Dense(500, activation='relu', kernel_regularizer=l2(reg))(x)
    x = Dense(500, activation='relu', kernel_regularizer=l2(reg))(x)
    x = Dense(500, activation='relu', kernel_regularizer=l2(reg))(x)
    x = Dense(500, activation='relu', kernel_regularizer=l2(reg))(x)
    x = Dense(500, activation='relu', kernel_regularizer=l2(reg))(x)
    x = Dense(output_size, activation='linear', kernel_regularizer=l2(reg))(x)

    model = Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=x)

    return model
```

Finally, a custom metric:

```
def root_mean_squared_error(y_true, y_pred):
    return K.sqrt(K.mean(K.square(y_pred - y_true), axis=-1))
```

I was using the following snippet to create and compile the model:

```
model = create_model(input_shape=X.shape[1:], output_size=y.shape[1])
model.compile(loss=root_mean_squared_error, optimizer='adamax')
```

As usual, I was using a checkpoint callback to save the model. To load the model, you need to pass the custom layers classes and metrics as well into `load_model` function:

```
def load_custom_model(path):
    return load_model(path, custom_objects={
        'LeakyReLU': LeakyReLU,
        'root_mean_squared_error': root_mean_squared_error
    })
```

Does it help?

Comment: @Adelin I've decided to answer with custom code. Probably that could help the author.

Comment: In my question the N is supposed to be large (maybe controlled by a hyper param), that's why I need a list or a loop. I understand that I can just repeat some line N times in the code, but it would be not ideal if N is, say, >10. I'll update my original statement to emphasize N is large.

Comment: @DavidM Sure, you can use loops, replace repeating fragments with `for-in` constructions. I think that the main modification you would like to do is to place your loop into your _model building function_ instead of `MyModel` class. Probably you don't need additional wrappers, use functional API, and then you can use any loops or conditional constructions you want.

Answer (score 1):

After having researched this to a great extent: I'm certain that there is no built-in, universal way to do this in Tensorflow/Keras.

There are, however, still ways to achieve the same goals but in a different way. The problem is that there's no universal solution to this in Tensorflow with any Keras layer, and so you'll have to approach it on a case-by-case basis.

So for example, if what you wanted to do is stack a bunch of `Dense` layers and then have some dimension of your input that would correspond to each one (simple example), what you would instead want to do is construct a custom `Dense` layer and add extra dimensions to its weights and biases, and then do the appropriate operations given some extra dimension in your input.

So ultimately the same (desired) operations would be performed here in the way that you want them to be, each input along some dimension would be put through a separate `Dense` layer with separate weights/biases: but it would be done concurrently, without any python looping. In essence, you would be reducing the size and complexity of the graph and performing the same operations in a more concurrent way; this ought to be much more efficient.

The strategy outlined here generalises to any layer/input type. It's not great news, in that it would be of very high value to us (users) if there were some standardised Keras-friendly way of stacking a bunch of layers and then passing input to them in a more concurrent way that didn't involve python looping but rather concatenating the internal parameters into a new dimension and managing alignment between an extra 'stacking' dimension in both the inputs and parameters.

Like, in the same way we have `tf.keras.Sequential` we could also benefit from something like `tf.keras.Parallel` as a universal solution to this common ML need.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you can solve this problem simply by using a for-loop when building the model. I'm not sure if you need any special layer so I will assume you only use Dense here:

```
def MyModel():
    input = Input(shape=...)
    x = input
    for i in range(N):
        x = Dense(number_of_nodes, name='dense %i' %i)(x)
        // Or some custom layers
    output = Dense(number_of_output)(x)

    return Model(inputs=input, outputs=output)
```